# Convert the following python code to C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm converting some python scripts to C#, and cannot get a web request to work. The python code is:

```
import json
import requests
import os

REST_URL = 'http://machinename:1234/webservicename'

payload = {'clientMessage': {
           "UserName": "fred",
           "MessageText": "message"
           }
       }
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(REST_URL, json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Can anyone convert this to C#? It's the "payload" variable I'm having trouble with - what's the C# equivalent? Thanks in advance

Edit - here's the C# code I have so far:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string payload = "{ 'clientMessage': { \"UserName\": fred, \"MessageText\": message } }";

string jsonDumps = serializer.Serialize(payload);
var content = new StringContent(jsonDumps, Encoding.UTF8, @"application/json");
var postResult = client.PostAsync(_restUrl, content).Result;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: [C# has dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Please show what you have in C#.

Comment: Added the C# code I have so far - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of way of doing this in C# is to create an [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), which you then serialize:

```
var payload = new
{
    clientmessage = new
    {
        UserName = "fred",
        MessageText = "message"
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
```

Result:

`{
  "clientmessage": {
    "UserName": "fred",
    "MessageText": "message"
  }
}`